# echo default value with Blade if field is empty

Tags: default, laravel-blade

In my view I have many Blade checks to detect if the field is empty or not.
I do know the short way like this:

```
<textarea rows="14">{{ $contact->Notes or 'Enter some notes.' }}</textarea>
```

The problem is, the variable Notes is always set.
Also if the database field is empty, simple because all table fields are send to the views.

How can I solve this in the cleanest way?

Answer (score 1):

Just check if a value is empty or not?

```
{{ !empty($timeline->custom_title) ? $timeline->custom_title : "Default title" }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use of `?:` [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Using `isset()` if the variable is set.

`{{ (isset($hey)) ? $contact->Notes : 'Enter some notes' }}`

Comment: this is the shorthand for this answer 
`{{ $contact->Notes or 'Enter some notes.' }}`

Answer (score 0):

**If the variable is always set**

```
{{{$contact->Notes != "" ? $contact->Notes :'Enter some notes.'}}}
```

**check both conditions value is set and it is not an empty**

```
{{{isset($contact->Notes) && $contact->Notes != "" ? $contact->Notes :'Enter some notes.'}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is to use the

> iif (inline if)

statement as follows:

```
{{ !isset($contact->Notes) ?: $contact->Notes }}
```